# How to control multiple current paths from one physical switch?

Tags: switches, analog, audio

I am working on a college project for my Analog Electronics class as part of my music technology class. I want to create a synthesizer where buttons can control Rf to change the oscillators frequency, or these same buttons can control the resistance in a separate circuit, which changes the brightness of an LED (this will then be used with a capacitor to create a pitch bend). However, I would need a toggle switch for each one of these buttons, to decide which way the signal is flowing. Is there a component I can buy that physically connects say, 5 switches, or would I need to create something basic myself?
Thank you!

Comment: You can probably use a rotary switch for this

Comment: Sounds like you just need a multi-pole switch. Both buttons and toggles are readily available in double pole versions, but you can find 3 and 4 pole switches in a more limited selection.

Comment: A quick look on Ebay for "6p3t rotary switch" (6 pole 3 throw {way}) gives quite a few options. What you appear to want is 5P2T, but no one lists that with 6P3T you can use the spare way to light some indicator lamps and the spare throw for some other function or a null option.